Save files like image, video, pdf to LG WebOs Tv app local storage
I am developing a LG webOs tv app. In my application, I have some images and videos which needed to be downloaded from my backend and saved to the local storage to use it later. I was able to download the file. Below is my javascript code to download.How to save it my application local storage?
async function downloadFile(url) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        
        const blob = await response.blob();
        return blob;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching file:', error);
    }
}


Use OPFS or IndexedDB depending on how old the browser engine is...

Your code that checks response.ok also needs to check the Response Content-Type header, because DNS names can be hijacked or retargeted in future and return HTTP 200 but with meaningless (or even malicious) body payloads which you need to check-for, otherwise your app may open up a route for malware...
